# Docker mount not working as expected in retrieving the file

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

below is my docker compose code. I am expecting the config file in elasticsearch.yml to be copied to ./config folder so that i can edit it and the container can read. However, i did this i can start the docker compose. ANything i missing. The sate i need create elasticsearch.yml in config folder. How can i create it sicne i havent duplicate the content to modify the yaml

```
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to bind a directory to a file. If your config file locally is named "elasticsearch.yml" just ommit the filename in the target. Should work then.

Comment: this i need to create the file? will the content of elasticsearch.yml will be copied and replace locally?

Comment: content from container copied and replaced from elasticsearch.yml in local

Comment: Ah you try to do it the other way round, right? So you try to mount the file from inside your container to your host environment?